# Difference between Least Squares (LS) and Ordinary Least Squares (OLS)

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, mathematical-optimization

Difference between Least Squares (LS) and Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) with respect to Linear regression.

What I found:-
On searching a bit,  I got a difference that in ordinary least squares we consider only the vertical distance between the predicted value and the given dependant variable, whereas, in the least Squares, we consider vertical and horizontal distance.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, add details if the explanation not complete or true.

Comment: Least Squares is usually meant to be OLS. But it can be different, like nonlinear LS, weighted LS etc. You need to look at the context. What you refer to is likely Total Least Squares. That is a bit special, so usually, the full name is used.

Comment: Ohh got it , thanks a lot @Erwin Kalvelagen !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is even more confusing because LS depends on wrt what deviation is considered.

Generally the usual OLS is wrt the deviations on ordinates of the points.

[image]

Copied from pp. 7-8 in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14819165/Regressions-coniques-quadriques-circulaire-spherique

Comment: thank you so much for your efforts. I think I am getting the idea , somewhat though. Based on what you shared , I can conclude that OLS is wrt Y axis, where as LS is wrt X and diagonal . Am I getting it write till some point ?

Comment: LS is wrt anything (someting not specified). This can be wrt Y axis ( then we can say OLS instead of ) or this can be wrt X axis, or wrt orthogonal distance, or wrt many other criteria of fitting. To know exactly wrt what, one have to consider the context of the problem. If nothing is specified about some criteria of fitting the most probable is that LS=OLS in this case.

Comment: Okay. I got the idea of how these terms are related. LS is a general term and it can vary (OLS, WLS ..) depending on the problem set and the objective we want to reach!             Thank you so much  @JJackquelin.